# Handle iPhone interruption in a music application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I've tried the code to avoid the sleep mode interruption. It's working, but now I have a problem with interruptions when a call or sms is coming in to the iPhone. The song in my music application is stopped at that time. I want to automatically resume the song where it was stopped once the call is over.

```
- (void) audioPlayerBeginInterruption: (AVAudioPlayer *) player {

if (playing) {

    playing = NO;

    interruptedOnPlayback = YES;

    [self updateViewForPlayerState];

}

}


- (void) audioPlayerEndInterruption: (AVAudioPlayer *) player {

if (interruptedOnPlayback) {

    [player prepareToPlay];

    [player play];

    playing = YES;

    interruptedOnPlayback = NO;

}

}
```

But it doesn't work. Please help me here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Apple's guide to Audio Interruptions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH11-SW1).